# How does shifting of numbers in selection sort work?

Tags: java, selection-sort

I am quite confused with this practice question. The question is

Write the state of the elements of the array below after each of the first 3 passes of the outermost loop of the selection sort algorithm.

```
int[] numbers = {45, 78, 89, 34, 23, 12, 67, 56};
selectionSort(numbers);

after pass 1: 
after pass 2:
after pass 3:
```

Comment: do you know, how the selection sort works? Hava a look at [Wikipedia] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort)

Comment: @JarlikStepsto Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I won't show your exact example since I think that is homework but I will show you with another example:

First the psudo code for an selection sort:

```
repeat (numOfElements - 1) times
  set the first unsorted element as the minimum
  for each of the unsorted elements
    if element < currentMinimum
      set element as new minimum
  swap minimum with first unsorted position
```

**Example:**

```
int[] numbers = {8, 23, 7, 34, 50, 15, 16};
selectionSort(numbers);
```

Set 8 as the current minimum, then iterate through the remaining unsorted elements to find the true minimum.

Swap the minimum (7) with the first unsorted element (8).

```
after pass 1: {7, 23, 8, 34, 50, 15, 16}
```

Swap the minimum (8) with the first unsorted element (23).

```
after pass 2: {7, 8, 23, 34, 50, 15, 16}
```

Swap the minimum (15) with the first unsorted element (23).

```
after pass 3: {7, 8, 15, 34, 50, 23, 16}
```

Swap the minimum (16) with the first unsorted element (34).

```
after pass 4: {7, 8, 15, 16, 50, 23, 34}
```

Swap the minimum (23) with the first unsorted element (50).

```
after pass 5: {7, 8, 15, 16, 23, 50, 34}
```

Swap the minimum (34) with the first unsorted element (50).

```
after pass 6: {7, 8, 15, 16, 23, 34, 50}
```

Sorted!

Comment: Thank you so much. This makes lot of sense.